# Scene Builder isnt starting in Netbeans cause of non-English Letters in Path

Tags: javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder

my Problem is the follows. My Notebook is owned by my employer, so i cant really change my Username. I have Admin rights whatsoever, but he made my Username with an 'ö' in it.
That really messes up most things that come up with parsing Paths.

So right now. After hours spent, i finally made JavaFX in NB to work. Not with a build-up jar, but at least in the IDE. For the Jar i gave up for now.

But the Scene Builder just throws a FNF-Exception. The Path shown is the correct one (generated by the IDE), but the "ö" is awfully missplaced. So i think it cant read the Path. NB is started with UTF-8 and every code i wrote so far i managed to do a workaround for that.

But not for this.. i dont know where i should specify a charset for that, if its even possible. i cant change the Path, so i have to get this to work.

Any hints?

[image]

Comment: Regarding your issues with JAR files: If you're getting a `FileNotFoundException` for an FXML _resource_ then you're likely not accessing the resource correctly.  You should be using methods such as `Class#getResource(String)` and `Class#getResourceAsStream(String)`.

Comment: As for your Scene Builder problem: You might be able to go to your Scene Builder installation, look for a file named something like `app\SceneBuilder.cfg` (that's what it's name on my Windows 10 computer), and insert the option needed to set the default encoding to UTF-8. But I haven't tried this.

Comment: Hey Slaw. The Problem with the Jar is nothing with the encoding Problem, more like the Fat-Jar or Jar with lib Dir gives "JavaFX runtime components missing.." There are many Threads on SO but none worked so far in the IDE + CL together. So i think i need to try more.
For the SB: i found that too and added it to JVM and arg-Options (standard JVM arg), but didnt change anything. "ö" still becomes "Ã¶" in the Error Output. I open it with Rightclick->Open in NB directly

Comment: What is working: Open SB directly in the Explorer and open the fxml then via the Dialog.